# Creating a raising edge to wake up the micro controller

Tags: resistors

Need help in understanding the following circuit.

[image]

The documentation says the STM32 micro controller can be woken up by a raising edge. My interpretation is that the pull up resistor connected between the 3.3V and the wakeup pin will pull the wakeup pin high on power on. But I am not able to understand the use of the second resistor between the wake up pin and the ground.

Comment: There's surely description and reasoning of this in the datasheet _EDIT:_ Or, is this thing not from the datasheet?

Comment: Got the circuit from the schematic diagram of the STM32VLDiscovery board. Doesn't include any description.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the datasheet, and to the diagram you are talking about?

Comment: http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/stm32vldiscovery_sch.zip - page 4 in MB913.pdf

Comment: http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00161566.pdf - 2.3.12 Low-power modes in page 16 says "The device exits Standby mode when an external reset (NRST pin), an IWDG reset, a rising edge on the WKUP pin, or an RTC alarm occurs."

Answer (score 2):

What you have encountered is a classic approach vendors take when they run out of pins on a device (or bonding space on silicon.) They merge pin functions.

This is the reason that your WKUP pin is also referred to as *PA0-WKUP*. You can catch references to both PA0 and WKUP throughout the datasheet. In the end, both physically join in the same pin.

---

From what I have found now about the use you see on the Discovery board, the pin is used in some sort of power-on/reset voltage monitoring process *and* WKUP at the same time. In your schematic, there are multiple occurrences of *PA0*. I'll leave it to you to Ctrl-F all of them.

Comment: Reasoning how the two resistors help in power-on/reset or WKUP at the same time will help. I stumbled up on this link where the answer uses a similar circuit http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93654/inverting-interrupt-edge-stm32-wake-up-pin

Comment: Will the resistors not form a voltage divider circuit?

Comment: @Deepan They will indeed form a voltage divider. But for the reasoning, you will have to dig into it yourself. Reading tons of datasheets is just a part of the process.